# How to get object of selected vuetify tab, not index?

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

By default, the `v-tabs` change event provides the index of the new tab. I'm facing issues with the wrong index if the tab items are dynamic.

```
<v-tabs :slider-size=4 v-model="tabs" @change="tabChangeHandler">
        <div v-for="(obj) in computedMasterTabsList" :key="'div'+obj.key">
          <v-tab v-if="obj.permission" :key="obj.key" @click="tabClickHandler(obj)">{{obj.label}}
          </v-tab>
       </div>
</v-tabs>
```

**Dynamic tab list example**:

```
[{key: 1, name:"A", permission: false, label:'Label A'}, {key: 2, name:"B", permission: true, label:'Label B'}, {key: 3, name:"C", permission: true, label:'Label C'}]
```

**Display Tabs**: Who has `permission: true`

On change of tabs, getting selected tab value is **0** or **1**.

I'm unable to get the selected object from the list using **0** and **1**.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `tabClickHandler` method just declare the `selected_tab` in data and use `indexof` method to get the selected tab index.

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/XWbXZKw?editors=1010;

```
this.selected_index = this.computedMasterTabsList.indexOf(obj);

mounted(){
    let i=0;
    for(i in this.computedMasterTabsList){
        if(this.computedMasterTabsList[i]['permission']==true){
          console.log(i)
          this.selected_index = i;
          break;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, man ! this worked. But what about the time when it loads, click handler is not being called, it's giving index 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You can write coden in mounted for setting default value